# Using Depth Buffer to avoid fragment calculations

Tags: c++, opengl-es

I have been checking the SO for this question, and even I found a similar question ([OpenGL ES 2.x: any way to reuse depth buffer for off-screen and on-screen rendering?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9967014/opengl-es-2-x-any-way-to-reuse-depth-buffer-for-off-screen-and-on-screen-render)) saying it can't be done, I found it differs from my intention.

My intention is to relieve the shader fragment opperations by using the depth buffer to discard occluded-gonnabes.

1. I set the DEPTH Writing On.
2. I disable the Color Writing (glColorMask(GL_TRUE,GL_TRUE,GL_TRUE,GL_TRUE);)
3. I set the DEPTH function to GL_LESS
4. I choose the simpler Vertex Shader and a void fragment shader (void main(void) {}).
5. I draw my scene
6. I set DEPTH writing off
7. I enable the Color Writing again
8. I draw each object again with his own shaders this time

But this does not work (I use OpenGL ES 2.0). If I disable Color Writing in first pass, I get no image (and some weird flickering), if I skip pass 2 and 7, i get no fps rate change.

**Why? Is there something wrong in my logic?** I dont mess with the FBOs, I just call the drawing of VBOs 2 times.

Comment: Yes weird flickering is expected with your approach also called "Z-Fighting". `glDepthFunc( GL_LEQUAL)` for the second pass may makes it a bit better.

Comment: no, the flickering contains no drawn primitives, is no Zfighting. All screen is backcolor clear. Is like the ClearColor changes from my Red to black at full speed.