# Sharing buffers in webgl

Tags: webgl, framebuffer

I'd like to be able to share the depth and stencil buffer(s) between the on-screen buffer and an off-screen buffer. (Or, to phrase it a different way, I want to be able to render to a texture using the on-screen depth and stencil buffer.)

I tried to bind a shared depth / stencil renderbuffer to the default framebuffer, only for it to error out with "cannot modify framebuffer 0". Ok, so I cannot modify the onscreen framebuffer.

I then tried to bind the default framebuffer's stencil / depth buffer(s) to the secondary render buffer, but, again, it errored out with "cannot query framebuffer 0".

My current workaround is to create two off-screen framebuffers, and at the end splat the main off-screen buffer to screen via a texture and a fullscreen quad. Not exactly pretty.

Unfortunately, webgl is based on OpenGL ES, and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9967014/opengl-es-2-x-any-way-to-reuse-depth-buffer-for-off-screen-and-on-screen-render) question suggests that there is no way to do this for OpenGL ES. As such, I suspect, although I hope that I am wrong, that there is no "better" way.

Comment: You say "not exactly pretty", but to me the principle of having *n* off-screen framebuffers for preprocessing, then blitting the "final" buffer to the screen with a fullscreen quad, sounds pretty standard.

Comment: Standard != good. That being said, good/bad to know that it is pretty standard. (Or, I suppose, standard, but not pretty?)

Comment: Hahaha, very true. I was going to say I'd take *standard* over *pretty* any day, but then I realized that I didn't mean it. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not possible.

WebGL 1.0 specification § 5.14.6:

> If framebuffer is null, the default framebuffer provided by the
>   context is bound and **attempts to modify or query state on target
>   FRAMEBUFFER will generate an INVALID_OPERATION error**.

Comment: Did WebGL2 change in this regard?